# Firebase Rest Api reading data from my model classes return null

Tags: java, json, rest, firebase-realtime-database, postman

I am trying to run a Get method in java Restful API. I have tried naming my model classes similar to my real-time firebase that wasn't the issue.

[This is my real-time firebase. reference is Devices/Lamp/Ambient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu3qF.png)

Here is my model class

```
 private String LightSwitch;
    private String DoorSwitch;

    // empty COnstructor
    public DeviceTest() { }

    public DeviceTest(String lightSwitch, String doorSwitch) {
        LightSwitch = lightSwitch;
        DoorSwitch = doorSwitch;
    }

    public String getLightSwitch() {
        return LightSwitch;
    }

    public void setLightSwitch(String lightSwitch) {
        LightSwitch = lightSwitch;
    }

    public String getDoorSwitch() {
        return DoorSwitch;
    }

    public void setDoorSwitch(String doorSwitch) {
        DoorSwitch = doorSwitch;
    }
}
```

Here is my readFirebase Method

```
public static List<DeviceTest> handleLight() {
        FireBaseService fbs = null;
        fbs = new FireBaseService();
      device = new DeviceTest();
        mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference ref = fbs.getDb()
                .getReference("/Devices/Lamp");
        ref.child("Ambient")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        device = dataSnapshot.getValue(DeviceTest.class);
                        mylist = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot unit : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            DeviceTest value = unit.getValue(DeviceTest.class);
                            mylist.add(value);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
//mylist.add(device);
        return mylist;
    }
```

Here is the GET method

```
@Path("/devices")
public class DeviceResource {
    
    DeviceService deviceService = new DeviceService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<DeviceTest> getCustomers(){
        return FireBaseService.handleLight();
    }
```

[Here is the null value in my postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5zSZ.png)

Comment: You cannot return the `mylist` as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: I have tried using interface callback. That didn't solve the problem

Comment: "That didn't solve the problem" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. So show us what you have tried by posting a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Post a new question or can I edit this post to give further information?

Comment: No, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are returning your list before it is populated with data.

`addValueEventListener` is asynchronus so your method do not wait for results of it.
`onDataChange` will be called when your data is ready but it can take a while, because it must download it from external source in network.

Have a look at this discussion: [How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Comment: Forgot to mention I have already tried using an interface class to get the value outside the method, but that didn't work either.